# Entropy in a closed box

Tags: machine-learning, classification, data

[image]

I have not understood why the maximum number of binary questions needed to reduce
uncertainty is essentially log(T).
If i have a ball in a box and 10 possible classes, is it enough to ask log(10) binary questions to know which is the class of the ball ? Sure ???

Comment: I have a suggestion for you for figuring out that. Ask someone to take a number between one to a hundred. Try to say that by asking 10 question. Every time ask whether it's greater than the half of available numbers or not. The maximum question will be 10 to say the exact number. You somehow try to limit the answers in a way that reduce the huge amount of possible answers.

Comment: The answer to the questions is binary, the questions, however does not need to be so simple.

Comment: "the maximum number of binary questions needed to reduce
uncertainty is essentially log(T)" --> How far is this principle applicable ? I don't understand completely why it's an important discover.

Answer (score 1):

The correct notation would be `math.ceil(log(T))`. Also what you are asking is/can formally be solved by [Binary Search Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search_tree). You can easily traverse it by `if-else` conditions and arrive at the correct result in `math.ceil(log(T))` steps.

It looks something like:

[image]

Just place the colour of the balls in the leaf nodes (last nodes). Your first question would be does the ball fall in the first 4 leaf nodes or the second group of 4 nodes.Then you can progress to level 2 and so on.

BST reduces the entropy by maximum amount. You can easily construct other unbalanced trees but then you will require more steps to arrive at a determinate result (in some cases) and less steps in some other cases. BST gives an absolute number of steps you must travel in order to reach the result.

More theory [here](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~gildea/csc282/slides/C12-bst.pdf).